# Horizontal enumeration in multiple columns with reasonable spacing

Tags: enumerate

I'm trying to create enumeration with horizontal lists and someone already provide the solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}

\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{tabto}

\newenvironment{tabbedenum}[1]
 {\NumTabs{#1}\inparaenum\let\latexitem\item
  \def\item{\def\item{\tab\latexitem}\latexitem}}
 {\endinparaenum}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabbedenum}{3}
\item text
\item text
\item text
\item text
\item text
\item text
\end{tabbedenum}
\end{document}
```

It works fine for text. However in I put math expressions the items will become too close to the each other and to the preceding paragraph. What should I put in the environment to adjust the preceding spacing, spacing between the items and after the items?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). Thanks for providing a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). But, it would be helpful if you actually included some math content that illustrates the problem you are describing.

Comment: How about `\begin{multicols}{3} \begin{itemize} \item ... \end{itemize} \end{multicols}` ?

Comment: Thanks Christian. It works if I have a single level enumeration. When I want to use multiple levels I put the standard latex enumeration as the first level and multicols as the second level but strange thing happen. The first two items (a) and (b) are fine but the third one (c) is not alinged correctly.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `shortlst` package: it allows for  items that are aligned in columns It's not in any distribution because of its license, but is available on CTAN. The `tablists` package can do almost the same thing, but its main advantage is that, if an item is too long to fit into a column, it *automatically* uses the next column. With tablists you have to to do it by hand in each case.

I have patched so that one can specify the number of columns (default is 3) and the interlining (default 1.5) through a system of keys (`nc=`ans `il=`). One can insert paragraphs of text with a `\paritem` command, only specifying the number of columns it will stretch over (optional argument,1 by default), and the text of the paragraph.
Here is a demo of a typical use — a list of answers to exercises:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[showframe,  nomarginpar]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{shortlst,setspace,xkeyval}%
\makeatletter
\newcounter{ncol}
\define@key{lex}{nc}[3]{\setcounter{ncol}{#1}}%% 3 columns by default
\define@key{lex}{il}[1.5]{\def\@intln{#1}}% interlining![1]
\newenvironment{tabenumerate}[1][]{%
\setkeys{lex}{nc,il,#1}
\settowidth{\labelwidth}{\mbox{(m)}}
\setlength{\leftmargini}{\dimexpr\labelwidth+\labelsep\relax}%[1][3]
\setlength{\shortitemwidth}{\dimexpr\linewidth/\value{ncol}-\labelwidth-2\labelsep\relax}%
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\ensuremath{(\alph{enumi})}}
\setstretch{\@intln}
\begin{shortenumerate}}%
{\end{shortenumerate}
 }%
 \newcommand\paritem[2][1]{\item \parbox[t]{#1\shortitemwidth}{\setstretch{1}#2}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\textbf{6 columns: }
\begin{tabenumerate}[nc = 6]
        \item $ x⁵  + x³  + 1 $
        \item $ \dfrac{x²  + 1}{x² -1} $
        \item $ \arctan u + \arctan\mfrac{1}{u} $
        \item $-∞ $
        \item  $ {]-1,1[}  ∪  {]2, + ∞[} $
        \item $\ln(e^{2x}-e^{x} + 1 )$
        \item $ \dfrac{1 + √{5}}{2} $
        \item  True
        \item False
        \item  $ √{\dfrac{5 + √{5}}{10}} $
        \item False
        \item Undecidable
\end{tabenumerate}

\textbf{3 columns: }
\begin{tabenumerate}[nc = 3,il = 2]
        \item $ x⁵  + x³  + 1 $
        \paritem[2]{This an intentionally extra super unreasonably long text}
        \item $ \dfrac{x²  + 1}{x² -1} $
        \item $ \arctan u + \arctan\mfrac{1}{u} $
        \item $-∞ $
        \item  $ {]-1,1[}  ∪  {]2, + ∞[} $
        \item $\ln(e^{2x}-e^{x} + 1 )$
        \item $ \dfrac{1 + √{5}}{2} $
        \item  True
        \item False
        \item  $ √{\dfrac{5 + √{5}}{10}} $
        \item False
        \item Undecidable
\end{tabenumerate}

\textbf{4 columns: }
\begin{tabenumerate}[nc = 4, il = 2]
        \item $ x⁵  + x³  + 1 $
        \item $ \dfrac{x²  + 1}{x² -1} $
        \item $ \arctan u + \arctan\mfrac{1}{u} $
        \item $-∞ $
        \item  $ {]-1,1[}  ∪  {]2, + ∞[} $
        \item $\ln(e^{2x}-e^{x} + 1 )$
        \item  True
        \item $ \dfrac{1 + √{5}}{2} $
        \item False
        \item  $ √{\dfrac{5 + √{5}}{10}} $
        \item False
        \item Undecidable
\end{tabenumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Bernard, it works fine. However I have 2 questions: (1) I tried to put tabenumerate within tabenumerate and it does not work, I guess it is not designed to do so? (2) tabenumerate does not hold long text line as it exceeds beyond the margin boundary. So If I want to do something like
1. some long text extend until the second line
   (a)            (b)              (c)
   (d)            (e)              (f)
2. other long text
I must use the standard latex enumeration for the first label and tabenumerate for the second label?

Comment: @sclee: (1) No  you cannot put any sort of list in these environments (see § 3 of shortlist documentation). (2)You can insert \parboxes. As one have to go back to a normal interlining inside the \parbox, I suppose, I added a `\paritem`command that lets you choose the number of columns that this \parbox will use. See my updated answer.